# Create factor with same length of the rown in a arbitrary interval

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to select the rows interval of a data frame (`ds`) by some level, in my case `STAND`. I tried the following:

```
# Packages
library(dplyr)

# Data
ds <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/my_ts_data.csv")
table(ds$STAND)
#          ALCINA_001A        ALDOSANI_031A        AROEIRAB_017A    ARROIOXAVIER_012A    ARROIOXAVIER_027B 
#                  182                  182                  182                  182                  182 
#       AZAMBUJAI_001A       AZAMBUJAI_018A      BARBANEGRA_404F       BARRONDAO_026A        BOAVISTA_019A 
#                  182                  182                  182                  364                  182 
#      BOMRECREIO_010A         CAMBARA_014A     CANAFISTULA_046A     CERRODACRUZ_013D         CHACARA_002A 
#                  182                  182                 2548                  182                  182 
#     CORDILHEIRA_004B   COXILHADOROSA_006B     CUENTRILHOI_019D     CUENTRILHOI_028A     CUENTRILHOI_040A 
#                  182                  182                  182                  182                  182 
#      DOISIRMAOS_001A    ESTRADAREALI_006A       FIGUEIRAS_012A          FOLLES_002A          FOLLES_011A 
#                  182                  182                  546                  182                  182 
#         GRAXAIM_002A         GUABIJU_007C         GUABIJU_010C         GUABIJU_011B         GUABIJU_016B 
#                  182                  182                  182                  182                  182 
#         GUABIJU_017B     GUAJUVIRAII_002A    MONTECASTELO_035A    MONTECASTELO_050B    PANTERANEGRA_006F 
#                  364                  728                  182                  182                  182 
#         PARAISO_035D         PARAISO_041A       PARAISOII_029A PASSODAESTANCIA_002A       PINHEIROS_040A 
#                  182                  182                  364                  182                  182 
#   PONTADASCANAS_021D        QUITERIA_225A           RAMOS_003B           RAMOS_014A     RANCHOVELHO_004A 
#                  182                  182                  182                  182                  182 
# RINCAODOSSOARES_004A RINCAODOSSOARES_005D RINCAODOSSOARES_015E      SANTAROSAI_026A         SAOBRAS_004B 
#                  182                  364                  546                  182                  182 
#         SAOJOAO_004A        SONHOMEU_004A      TAQUAREMBO_003F    TAQUAREMBOII_002A       TERRADURA_033B 
#                  182                  182                  182                  182                  182 
#         VACACAI_009D      VENDAVELHA_014B       VILAPALMA_012B       VILAPALMA_025A       VILAPALMA_026A 
#                  182                  182                  182                  182                  182 
#       VILAPALMA_030A       VILAPALMA_030C       VILAPALMA_033C       VILAPALMA_033K 
#                  182                  182                  182                  182
```

This is good not because I need length 182 for all `STAND` level and for take the correct values I need the interval 1:182 by level (Wrong factors are `GUABIJU_017B,GUAJUVIRAII_002A,RINCAODOSSOARES_005D,CANAFISTULA_046A,RINCAODOSSOARES_015E,BARRONDAO_026A`). The other values must be ignored.
My desired output is:

```
table(ds$STAND)
#          ALCINA_001A        ALDOSANI_031A        AROEIRAB_017A    ARROIOXAVIER_012A    ARROIOXAVIER_027B 
#                  182                  182                  182                  182                  182 
#       AZAMBUJAI_001A       AZAMBUJAI_018A      BARBANEGRA_404F       BARRONDAO_026A        BOAVISTA_019A 
#                  182                  182                  182                  182                  182 
#      BOMRECREIO_010A         CAMBARA_014A     CANAFISTULA_046A     CERRODACRUZ_013D         CHACARA_002A 
#                  182                  182                 182                  182                  182 
#     CORDILHEIRA_004B   COXILHADOROSA_006B     CUENTRILHOI_019D     CUENTRILHOI_028A     CUENTRILHOI_040A 
#                  182                  182                  182                  182                  182 
#      DOISIRMAOS_001A    ESTRADAREALI_006A       FIGUEIRAS_012A          FOLLES_002A          FOLLES_011A 
#                  182                  182                  182                  182                  182 
#         GRAXAIM_002A         GUABIJU_007C         GUABIJU_010C         GUABIJU_011B         GUABIJU_016B 
#                  182                  182                  182                  182                  182 
#         GUABIJU_017B     GUAJUVIRAII_002A    MONTECASTELO_035A    MONTECASTELO_050B    PANTERANEGRA_006F 
#                  182                  182                  182                  182                  182 
#         PARAISO_035D         PARAISO_041A       PARAISOII_029A PASSODAESTANCIA_002A       PINHEIROS_040A 
#                  182                  182                  182                  182                  182 
#   PONTADASCANAS_021D        QUITERIA_225A           RAMOS_003B           RAMOS_014A     RANCHOVELHO_004A 
#                  182                  182                  182                  182                  182 
# RINCAODOSSOARES_004A RINCAODOSSOARES_005D RINCAODOSSOARES_015E      SANTAROSAI_026A         SAOBRAS_004B 
#                  182                  182                  182                  182                  182 
#         SAOJOAO_004A        SONHOMEU_004A      TAQUAREMBO_003F    TAQUAREMBOII_002A       TERRADURA_033B 
#                  182                  182                  182                  182                  182 
#         VACACAI_009D      VENDAVELHA_014B       VILAPALMA_012B       VILAPALMA_025A       VILAPALMA_026A 
#                  182                  182                  182                  182                  182 
#       VILAPALMA_030A       VILAPALMA_030C       VILAPALMA_033C       VILAPALMA_033K 
#                  182                  182                  182                  182
```

Please, any help with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words, you want the first 182 rows by groups of `STAND`? If so, you can use `slice_head`:

```r
library(dplyr)
slice_head(ds, by = STAND, n = 182)
```

Note that other syntaxes in `dplyr` include:

```r
ds |> 
  group_by(STAND) |> 
  slice_head(n = 182) |> 
  ungroup()

ds |> 
  filter(row_number() %in% 1:182, .by = STAND)
```